# getting parameters from url in php adds special characters

Tags: php, url, parameters, character, addition

I have a javascript code that calls a function of a PHP api to insert a row in my database.

```
var url = 'http://myapi/OfertasVentaOnline/api.php?method=update&function=categoria&id='+id+'&idCategoria='+id_categoria+'&descripcion='+descripcion+'&format=json';


    $.getJSON(url, function (data){     

    });
```

a sample of this url:

```
"http://myapi/OfertasVentaOnline/api.php?method=create&function=categoria&id=9999&idCategoria=3&descripcion=test%new%category&format=json"
```

in the url i replace the spaces for % in the descripcion parameter, as shown here the url is created correctly.

then I got my api who gets the call and decodes it. in the function that i use to decode and get the parameters:

```
$descripcion_cool = str_replace("%"," ",$_GET['descripcion']);

echo utf8_decode($descripcion_cool);

$query = 'INSERT INTO `Categorias`(`idCamping`, `idCategoria`, `descripcion`) VALUES (
                    "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']).'",
                    "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['idCategoria']).'",
                    "'.mysql_real_escape_string($descripcion_cool).'")';
```

this outputs this:

```
test new?tegoryINSERT INTO `Categorias`(`idCamping`, `idCategoria`, `descripcion`) VALUES (
                    "9999",
                    "3",
                    "test new�tegory")null
```

as you can see, php add some special characters to the url parameters. What am i doing wrogn ? thanks

PD: in my php file i tried to add:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

but it keeps doing the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always `encodeURIComponent` query string parameters. Or let jQuery do that for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the `$_GET['var']` variable already return an escaped string?

Comment: You must escape it so that `$_GET` can un-escape it properly.

Comment: He's escaping it properly, but is then decoding it twice more after the $_GET return..

Comment: OP is doing both wrong :)

Comment: You're right; I didn't notice the lack of 20. Should be escaped using either `%20` or `+`. If OP is getting this information from some predetermined source, the input should be encoded to use the above formats BEFORE sending to the page, not after (as the %ne and %ca are being interpreted as escaped characters)

Comment: Instead of manually encoding, `encodeURIComponent` is always good to use as @SalmanA stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're sending param values having spaces, you are encoding it by replace space with `%` . Actually, you don't have to do that. You can use `encodeURIComponent()` method if you want to encode params/quesrystings being passed over. And if you want to encode url, then use `encodeURI()`

```
 description = encodeURIComponent(description);

var url = 'http://myapi/OfertasVentaOnline/api.php?method=update&function=categoria&id='+id+'&idCategoria='+id_categoria+'&descripcion='+descripcion+'&format=json';



    $.getJSON(url, function (data){     

    });
```

This will safely enocode url.

Comment: Nah. `encodeURIComponent` should be applied on URI components (e.g. query string names/values), not the URI itself.